# Select Specific data created in year in my parent table

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good day Im have trouble in my models.py
I want to select date_created year = "2019" in my parent table but im having an error is there another way? thank you in advance !

```
class ProjectName(models.Model):
    BacProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Please include the error trace in your question

Comment: class BacFileUpload(models.Model):
     Sproject = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName__date_created__year=2019, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)



#error messages
    Sproject = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName__date_created__year=2019, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'

Comment: how to can i display date_created year = 2019 only

Comment: You should edit your question and include the error trace there, not in the comment section. Comment section has limited characters capability

Comment: if you want to filter date by year, you can use 'year'
in example : date_created__year = '2019'